# Is there a way to use LaTeX formatting for Wordpress?

Tags: customization

There are numerous ways to write LaTeX ***equations*** in Wordpress; this is ***NOT*** what I am asking.

Is there any way to take LaTeX formatting (i.e. not in math mode, commands like `\begin{itemize}`) and translate it to CSS or some other format usable by Wordpress?

It is frustrating because I am able to format lists (for example) very well in LaTeX, but even simple things using lists I am unable to accomplish in Wordpress (e.g. make the list numbers bold).

I am aware of [LaTeX to Wordpress](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/latex-to-wordpress/), but it is primarily for the equations; it does not preserve my formatting to a significant extent.

**Note:** I am new to this website, I am not sure what is on-topic or not, this might be essentially a question about CSS (StackOverflow?), but maybe not. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/css-based-latex-formatting) is the opposite direction.